# Remove class from all elements and then toggle it on selected element

Tags: javascript, class

I'm trying to remove a class from all rows and toggle it on the selected row. I'm trying to achieve this in javascript. I have a bunch of rows that look something like the following. Currently, I'm having inconsistent results where sometimes the other rows remain open. What am I doing wrong?

```
<section class="table-body">
  <section class="table-row u-flex">
    <div class="table-category">
       ...
    </div>
  </section>
  <section class="table-row u-flex">
    <div class="table-category">
       ...
    </div>
  </section>
   ...
</section>
```

Javascript

```
function openMenu(e) {
  for( let i = 0; i < e.closest('.table-body').children.length; i++ ) { 
    document.querySelector('.table-row').classList.remove('is-open');

  }
  // add the active class to the row you just clicked
  if (e.closest('.table-row') !== null) {
      e.closest('.table-row').classList.toggle('is-open'); 
  }
}
```

Comment: How do you call `openMenu`

Comment: document.querySelector() returns an array of elements. You are trying to access it like a single element. Also, you are getting the length of e.closest than are re-querying from the doucment level. You should query the rows at the beggining.

Comment: @EricHerlitz I'm calling it with an onClick event.

Answer (score 0):

The problem, as I see it, is, that first you remove the class from every `.table-row` and then toggle it on the one that triggered the event.

This leads to the following scenarios:

**1.** Trigger row has class `"is-open"`:

- **Expected:** every row is closed afterwards.
- **Actual behavior:** first the `"is-open"` class is removed in the for loop but then it get's added again, with the toggle command.

**2.** Trigger row doesn't have class "is-open"

- **Expected:** every row is closed except for the trigger one.
- **Actual behavior:** as expected.

What I'd do is the following:

```
function openMenu(e) {
    const openRow = !e.closest('.table-row').classList.contains('is-open');
    for( let i = 0; i < e.closest('.table-body').children.length; i++ ) { 
        document.querySelector('.table-row').classList.remove('is-open');
    }
    if (openRow) {
       e.closest('.table-row').classList.add('is-open'); 
    }
}
```

This should do the trick.

Comment: This didn't work and it introduced buggy behavior. Sometimes the menu closes sometimes it does not. Also, it's not removing the "is-open" from all rows. I have multiple rows with the class "is-open" at the same time.

Comment: After looking at it more closely it appears that your code only works on the first ".table-row". It opens all the other ones, but it doesn't close them.